# Implementing keyboard short cut using "Keyboard.IsKey..." rescales the window, WHY?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

Windows 10.0.18362, 
Visual Studio 16.4.5,
.NET 4.8.03752

Hi there

I wanted to setup a keyboard short cut to do something. So I set up the following code:

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.D))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Basically it works. The only (very nasty) thing that happens is that as soon as I implement "Keyboard.IsKey...(...)" into the code, run it, then pressing any key makes the window scales down (to 
about 80%) totally out of nowhere.

I can replace the condition with "true" and it just runs as expected without any random out of nowhere scaling.

Did any one out there experience something similar? This behaviour does absolutely not make any sense, so searching for solutions obviously leads in dead ends only.

Thanks for any help or recommendation.

Comment: Not sure on the issue, but you could also look at `e` - the `KeyEventArgs` that are passed to the event that should contain the pressed key. Would avoid using `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` if for some reason that's causing an issue

Comment: Oh yes, your input helped!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RadioMan85, based on my test, I can not reproduce your problem. Can you possibly provide more details? It will be helpful for me to understand what is wrong with you.

Comment: @Jack J Jun: I wouldn't wonder if this issue behaves different just on an other computer. I guess that it may also has to do with the current display setup... and so on. Because the input of Charleh made me get rid of that issue and the time for the current project is running low, I can't spend more time for this issue. But thx a lot for your help!!